# rerun Python script if error occured

Tags: python

I am scraping twitter data using their Streaming API, sometimes, I will get

```
  File "//swigel_local/Shared/Resources/Tools/Twitter/Streaming/StreamingTwitter.py", line 68, in <module>
    stream.filter(track=TRACK_TERMS)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 445, in filter
    self._start(async)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 361, in _start
    self._run()

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 294, in _run
    raise exception

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 263, in _run
    self._read_loop(resp)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 313, in _read_loop
    line = buf.read_line().strip()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

And this will stop my program. Is there a way that I can rerun my program automatically when this error occurs?

My code is :

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        if status.retweeted:
            return

        text = status.text
        created = status.created_at
        id_str = status.id_str
        retweets = status.retweet_count
        blob = TextBlob(text)
        sent = blob.sentiment

        table = db[settings.TABLE_NAME]
        try:
            table.insert(dict(
                text = text,
                created = created,
                id_str = id_str,
                retweet_count = retweets,
                polarity = sent.polarity,
                subjectivity = sent.subjectivity,
            ))
        except ProgrammingError as err:
            print(err)


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            #returning False in on_data disconnects the stream
            return False
stream.filter(track=TRACK_TERMS)
```

I don't know why the error happens. But I think it has something to do with the change I made recently.

Before, my table in MySQL has utf8 collation, but this will cause warning, then I read articles, and changed my table to utf8mb4 unicode. 
The warning disappeared and the program runs fine. But sometimes, the above error would occur when the program is running.

```
def _read_loop(self, resp):
    charset = resp.headers.get('content-type', default='')
    enc_search = re.search('charset=(?P<enc>\S*)', charset)
    if enc_search is not None:
        encoding = enc_search.group('enc')
    else:
        encoding = 'utf-8'

    buf = ReadBuffer(resp.raw, self.chunk_size, encoding=encoding)

    while self.running and not resp.raw.closed:
        length = 0
        while not resp.raw.closed:
            line = buf.read_line().strip()
            if not line:
                self.listener.keep_alive()  # keep-alive new lines are expected
            elif line.isdigit():
                length = int(line)
                break
            else:
                raise TweepError('Expecting length, unexpected value found')
```

Comment: Identify and fix the bug or just catch the exception and ignore it

Comment: You should not simply ignore errors like that. It's a good indication of an error in your code and may occur in a large percentage of your executions of that code if left unchecked. It is better to identify the reason why you are getting a `None` value and either performing a check for `None` (or falseyness) and not executing that code or fixing the your potential logic error.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way that I can rerun my program automatically when this error occurs?

You could write an external application that monitors the system, detects crashes of your application and restarts it.

**BUT** I wouldn't recommend it!

The right solution is:

- Identify the cause of this issue and fix it!
- Wrap problematic code segments using `try .. except`, catch such errors (e.g. `AttributeError`) and handle them accordingly

Comment: I just couldn't identify the cause of the issue, could you help me with that?

Comment: @Dylan, look at the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`. You can see that it says that you call `strip` from a `None` value. Since you are calling `buf.read_line().strip()`, it means that `buf.read_line()` returns `None`. I don't know exactly what `buf` is, but it might be its way to say `EOF`. Read the manual for that library and check when it throws AttributeError

Comment: thanks for your advice, I go to the library and pasted the related lines in my original post. Can I modify code in a library?

Comment: @Dylan. First of all, I want to correct my last comment: Check when `buf.read_line()` returns `None`, not when it raises `AttributeError`.  I see the new code. I don't know what `ReadBuffer` is, but you should check when its `read_line()` method returns `None`. A different fix might be changing your `while` loop to `line = buf.read_line(); while line: line = line.strop() ...`